# How to ignore files or folders in a SVN project

Tags: svn

We would like to ignore certain files and folders for the entire project. CVS used to have .cvsignore where you can specify this information and commit this to be part of the CVS.

Looks like in SVN you will have to set properties at the folder or file level, which is kind of inconvenient for all developers. Is there a simpler way similar to .cvsignore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could `svn -R propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .` as described in more detail [here](http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2005/svnignore-and-svnkeywords) be a solution?